# Как сделать эффект преломления света на изображении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

Реально ли сделать такой эффект с помощью css или js?

Чтобы при наведении на определенную область картинки (при *hover*) срабатывал такой эффект:

[image: Эффект преломления света]

Comment: Почему бы не сделать это в фотошопе?

Comment: Сори забыл указать... при движение мышки должен быть паралакс преломление света

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Укажите все необходимые детали прямо в тексте вопроса ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/885356/edit))

Comment: И да, картинку тоже словами опишите, "такой эффект" это слишком невнятно

Comment: Любой такой эффект легко делается при помощи фрагментного шейдера, конкретно ваш - смещением текстурных координат в области, которую вы зададите как интерактивную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даю Вам направление, а далее, с помощью фигур, фильтров, анимации и стилей, дело должно "пойти в гору")) Метод прост, но могут возникнуть проблемы при резиновой вёрстке (хотя, я не проверял, как это всё будет работать с относительными единицами):

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.refract');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  let x = event.clientX - 127;
  let y = event.clientY;

  let polygon = `polygon(${x}px 0px, ${x + 95}px 0px, ${x + 255}px 345px, ${x + 160}px 345px)`;
  container.style['-webkit-clip-path'] = polygon;
  container.style['clip-path'] = polygon;
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZt9f.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.refract {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZt9f.jpg') 5px 5px no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(130px 0px, 225px 0px, 385px 345px, 290px 345px);
  clip-path: polygon(130px 0px, 225px 0px, 385px 345px, 290px 345px);
}

.focused {
  animation: 2s infinite alternate satblur;
}

@keyframes satblur {
  0%,
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: saturate(1.9) blur(0.0px);
    filter: saturate(1.9) blur(0.0px);
  }
  30%,
  70% {
    -webkit-filter: saturate(1.9) blur(2.9px);
    filter: saturate(1.9) blur(2.9px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: saturate(0.1) blur(2.9px);
    filter: saturate(0.1) blur(2.9px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="refract focused"> </div>
```

> PS Рекомендую для просмотра не раскрывать страницу, ибо не адаптировалось.

Источники: [раз](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/06/css-shapes-clipping-and-masking/), [два](https://webref.ru/css/value/filter), [три](http://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/).