# как сделать маску?

Tags: css

Как сделать такую маску, что-бы можно было правый квадрат центрировать как сверху так и снизу (то есть что-бы можно было привязать паралакс)?

пример: [recordit.co/EYQFhRIBlD](http://recordit.co/EYQFhRIBlD)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ставьте задачи яснее и сразу. В каком диапазоне возможно смещение? CSS или SVG? Будут ли эти блоки пустыми или в них будет текст? _Почему клещами надо всё вытягивать?_ Может кому пригодится для отправной точки - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/885462/265406

Comment: вкратце - http://recordit.co/EYQFhRIBlD

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: @UModeL, не надо тут ни кому ставить задачи, тут не бесплатный ***ФПИЛАН-КЛУБ***, мы здесь делимся опытом и помогаем друг другу, а не делаем работу за других...

Comment: @Air ну, я делаю это во-первых для себя, просто практика в свободное время. Вот, закроют сейчас вопрос, и это ни то, чтобы другим не поможет, но даже этому человеку. Четыре доброхота отметили тревогой, а могли бы поправить человека или сами внесли бы правки. Вот, как нужно было задать вопрос? Описать в заголовке форму маски?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вижу, что стартовые условия меняются на ходу.

```js
var oMoveBlock = document.querySelector('.block_move');
var nBlockCoord, polygon, y = 0;

function onMoveBlock(e) {
  nBlockCoord = y + e.movementY;
  if (nBlockCoord < -160) { nBlockCoord = -160; }
  if (nBlockCoord > 200) { nBlockCoord = 200; }
  y = nBlockCoord;
  polygon = `polygon(
    330px ${y + 160}px, 
    520px ${y + 160}px, 
    575px ${y + 195}px, 
    575px ${y + 400}px, 
    385px ${y + 400}px, 
    330px ${y + 365}px
    )`;
  oMoveBlock.style['-webkit-clip-path'] = polygon;
  oMoveBlock.style['clip-path'] = polygon;
};

function onBlockMouseup() {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMoveBlock);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onBlockMouseup);
};
oMoveBlock.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  this.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMoveBlock);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onBlockMouseup);
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body, .block_back, .block_move { height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; }

body { background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 8px 8px, radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px, radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.1) 15%, transparent 20%) 8px 9px; background-color:#0e1634; background-size:16px 16px; }

.block_back {
  background: url('//picsum.photos/610/496?image=133') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(40px 35px, 355px 35px, 450px 90px, 450px 441px, 135px 440px, 40px 385px);
  clip-path: polygon(40px 35px, 355px 35px, 450px 90px, 450px 441px, 135px 440px, 40px 385px);
}

.block_move {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('//picsum.photos/610/496?image=133') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(15%) contrast(20%) brightness(1.8);
  filter: grayscale(15%) contrast(20%) brightness(1.8);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(330px 160px, 520px 160px, 575px 195px, 575px 400px, 385px 400px, 330px 365px);
  clip-path: polygon(330px 160px, 520px 160px, 575px 195px, 575px 400px, 385px 400px, 330px 365px);
}
```

```html
<div class="block_back"></div>
<div class="block_move"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь