# Как наложить одну картинку на другую? В HTML и CSS?

Tags: html, css

Есть две фото на одном ноутбук на другом разодранный ноутбук силно сложно соединить две картинки в одну и как бы водишь лупой по целому а там где не большая лупа так показывает нужнюю картинку с разобранным ноутам. Типо ренгин лупа.

Comment: Погугли плагин какой-нибудь, такое "на коленке" за пару минут не сваяешь, да и зачем костыли городить

Comment: [Так](http://jsfiddle.net/vk0zwayo/)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/885462/265406 или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/913377/265406